# Updating Bokeh figure with pandas dataframe queries

Tags: pandas, slider, bokeh

I have a pandas DataFrame named `complete` that contains the locations of car accidents by latitude, longitude, whether or not a drunk driver was involved, and the hour of the day of the accident.

I am wanting to update the figure using data of pandas queries based on the value of a slider. I am new to Bokeh and I have no experience in Javascript, so the CustomJS for Widgets section of the Bokeh Docs isn't making much sense to me, but I assume that is what I need to use.

I have the the intended behavior working in a Jupyter Notebook using the `interact()` method from `ipywidgets`. Can somebody help me replicate the behavior using Bokeh Sliders?

```
circleS = Circle(x='sob_x', y='sob_y', size=5, fill_alpha=.2, 
                 line_alpha=0, fill_color='navy')
circleD = Circle(x="dr_x", y="dr_y", size=6, fill_alpha=.2, 
                 line_alpha=0, fill_color='red')

source_drunk = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
        sob_x=[],
        sob_y=[],
        dr_x=[],
        dr_y=[]
    ))

p = figure(title="Fatal Car Accidents")#, plot_width=900, plot_height=600)
p.patches('x', 'y', fill_alpha=0, 
          source=source_states, line_color="black", line_width=1)

p.add_glyph(source_drunk, circleS)
p.add_glyph(source_drunk, circleD)

sober = complete[complete["DRUNK_DR"]==0]
drunk = complete[complete["DRUNK_DR"]!=0]

def update(time):
    time = (time + 5) % 23
    time_string = str(time % 12) + ":00"
    if time >= 12:
        time_string += "PM"
    else:
        time_string += "AM"
    print time_string

    source_drunk.data['sob_y'] = sober.loc[sober["HOUR"]==time, "LATITUDE"]
    source_drunk.data['sob_x'] = sober.loc[sober["HOUR"]==time, "LONGITUD"]
    source_drunk.data['dr_y'] = drunk.loc[drunk["HOUR"]==time, "LATITUDE"]
    source_drunk.data['dr_x'] = drunk.loc[drunk["HOUR"]==time, "LONGITUD"]

    print len(source_drunk.data['sob_x'])
    print len(source_drunk.data['dr_x'])

    push_notebook()

show(p)

# --- new jupyter notebook cell ----
interact(update, time=(0,23))
```